# Algorithm to categorize episode-file names efficiently

Tags: c#, beginner, file-system

I'm trying to categorize file names of anime episodes *(for now)* into appropriate title based categories. The Show-titles are parsed from an [XML file](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/reports.php?id=155&nlist=all) (I got from Anime News Network).

**EDIT:** The passed on `backgroundWorker` object type variable is just to facilitate GUI update as this algorithm runs on a secondary thread.

**DESCRIPTION:** The algorithm itself is pretty straightforward, it finds matches for each keyword in the file name with a set list of show-titles and assigns a score corresponding to the show-title. After all the keywords are checked for matches, the show-title with the highest score is given as the `category` to the file.
There are a few tweaks to boost the score in certain cases as well, like if the directory names match with the same show-title and if the score and the show-title length are almost the same number.

**ADDITION:** Class level variable declarations for context

```
OpenDialogView openDialog;
List<DirectoryInfo> dirList;
BackgroundWorker AnalyzerThread;

// Analyzer Components
public static char[] removablesNum = new char[] { '.', '_', '-', ' ', '^', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*', '~', '`', '?', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '+', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
public static char[] removables = new char[] { '.', '_', '-', ' ', '^', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*', '~', '`', '?', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '+' };
public static string animeDBPath = "ANN_AnimeDB_20-12-2015.xml";
public string parentPath, outputPath;
public List<string> titles;
public List<Children> notSortedFiles;
public List<Category> sortedFiles;
```

**CODE:**

```
#region Analyzer 
private void RunAnalysis(object backgroundWorker)
{
    titles = LoadXML(animeDBPath, "item", "name");

    List<DirectoryInfo> dirs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    List<FileInfo> allFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

    // Find all directories
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dirList)
    {
        dirs.AddRange(d.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }
    // Add the parent directory as well
    dirs.AddRange(dirList);

    // Find all the files
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
    {
        allFiles.AddRange(dir.EnumerateFiles());
    }

    sortedFiles = SortFiles(allFiles, backgroundWorker);
}


private List<Category> SortFiles(List<FileInfo> allFiles, object backgroundWorker)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    int fileCount = 0;

    foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
    {
        fileCount++;
        string[] subStrings = file.Name.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // score holds a value for each title, highest score indicates closer match
        int[] score = new int[titles.Count];
        bool hasAScore = false;

        // list's length - 1 to avoid extensions from being checked
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subStrings.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                // @\b defines the match to be specific to whole words
                if (Regex.IsMatch(titles[i], @"\b" + subStrings[j] + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    // If a match is found, check the directory paths to enforce the match
                    foreach (string s in file.Directory.Name.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(titles[i], @"\b" + s + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        {
                            score[i]++;
                        }
                    }

                    score[i]++;
                    hasAScore = true;
                    // Console.WriteLine("Found match with title '{0}' with string '{1}' from file '{2}'", titles[j], subStrings[i], file.Name);
                }
            }
            // if the percentage of word matches and total words in the title is > 80% (arbitrary)
            // To avoid false matches with longer titles
            // boost the score
            int titleWordCount = titles[i].Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
            if ((100 * (score[i]) / (2 * titleWordCount)) > 80)
            {
                score[i] += 2;
            }
        }
        if (hasAScore)
        {
            // Find the highest score in the list and use it's title value as the title of the Category
            string titleName = titles[Array.IndexOf(score, score.Max())];
            bool exists = false;
            // Check through all the categories if it already exists, otherwise add a new one
            // TODO perhaps check this in the class's constructor
            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                if (c.Name == titleName)
                {
                    c.AddChildren(new Children(file), titleName);
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!exists)
            {
                categories.Add(new Category(new Children(file), titleName));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Files without a score were not matched with any existing category
            notSortedFiles.Add(new Children(file));
        }
        // Console.WriteLine("File: '{0}' has a max score of {1}", file.Name, score.Max());

        // Update Progress
        // Send percentComplete to the backgroundWorker and the current file number
        int progressPercentage = 100 * fileCount / allFiles.Count;
        // Only the ReportProgress method can update the UI
        (backgroundWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressPercentage, fileCount);
    }
    return categories;
}

private List<string> LoadXML(string filePath, string descendant, string element)
{
    // Load the db
    XDocument db = XDocument.Load(@filePath);
    List<string> titles = new List<string>();

    var query = from c in db.Root.Descendants(descendant)
                    // Only do anime
                select c.Element("type").Value == "TV" ? c.Element(element).Value : "null";

    foreach (string animeName in query)
    {
        titles.Add(animeName);
    }
    // Sanitize "null" additions
    titles.RemoveAll(value => value == "null");
    titles.Sort();

    titles = DeAccentTitles(titles);

    return titles;
}

private List<string> DeAccentTitles(List<string> titlesToClean)
{
    List<string> sanitizedTitles = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in titlesToClean)
    {
        string nfdNormalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in nfdNormalizedString)
        {
            if(CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
        }
        sanitizedTitles.Add(builder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));
    }
    return sanitizedTitles;
}
#endregion
```

**Sample File names:**

```
ShingekinoKyojinOVA-01(480p)[Hatsuyuki-Kaitou][D8E8CC75].mkv -- Expected Category "Shingeki no Kyojin"
(Hi10)_Gosick_-_22_The_Christmas_Carol_Adorns_the_Happiness_by_the_Window_(BD_720p)_(Broken).mkv -- Expected Category "Gosick"
Manyuu.Hiken-chou.04.HD.BD.Kira.ACB.mkv -- Expected Category "Manyu Hiken-cho"
Commie_Steins Gate 01 Prologue to the Beginning and End.mkv -- Expected Category "Steins Gate"
Commie_Steins_Gate_02_BD_720p_AnimeKens.com.mkv -- Expected Category "Steins Gate"
```

**Extract from the Source XML File:**

```
<report>
    <args>
        <type>anime</type>
        <name></name>
        <search></search>
    </args>
    <item>
        <id>17938</id>
        <gid>721551383</gid>
        <type>ONA</type>
        <name>Koyomimonogatari</name>
        <precision>ONA</precision>
        <vintage>2016-01-09</vintage>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>17937</id>
        <gid>1319318627</gid>
        <type>TV</type>
        <name>Qualidea Code</name>
        <precision>TV</precision>
    </item>
</report>
```

I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454948/sort-episodes-into-anime-based-categories-from-file-folder-names) on SO regarding the approach to this kind of categorization problem (if you need more context).

**EDIT:** My code runs fine but as mentioned above, produces surprising false-positives. It's also quite slow, that's why I'm looking for a code review to improve it's performance and possibly realize the cause of the false-positives.

By the way, since this is a statistical algorithm, a few wrong results doesn't mean it's not working. It's working to an acceptable standard and improving correct prediction rate is not the primary concern.

Comment: It's unclear to me *what* exactly you are asking for. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. We review fully working code and make it better. Does this apply to the code you posted? Are you looking for a code review? If your code is not working as you want, or you're not looking for code review, then your question is off-topic. Please read [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help center page for more details.

Comment: My code runs fine, but is a quite slow. I was looking for ways to improve it. I've edited the question accordingly. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: could you please give us a sample of the xml please?

Comment: I have added an extract from the XML file, otherwise the link to the XML (in the question) leads to the same file.

Comment: Here's a suggestion, your `SortFiles` method has four nested loops.  Whatever is running inside those loops better run fast.  I'd bet that those Regex calls are slowing things down.  If you could find a way to replace them with simple string manipulations you might see things speed up.  If you can't do without the Regexes, precompile them http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance

Comment: Another suggestion, looks like you have two identical calls to `file.Directory.Name.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`: one at the beginning of your first loop in `SortFiles` and another in your second-deepest loop.  It looks like you can replace the second call with your `subStrings` variable without effecting anything.  This should help.

Comment: Yea it's those Regexes inside the loop slowing everything down. The second Regex call was originally called after the first one in all cases (unlike the if-conditional now). It was twice as slower then. Don't think I can pre-compile the regex, because each call has a different 'match' pattern. Unless I were to pre-compile all 3000 and so patterns beforehand.

Comment: The second call is on the path of the directory. It will be a different string in most cases

Comment: You might want to emphasize in the last paragraph that since this is a statistical algorithm, getting some wrong results doesn't mean that the program is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have time to look at `SortFiles` more closely right now, so just some general remarks:

1. I found it useful for readability to prefix private class members with `_` so make them easily distinguishable from local variables and parameters. I was stumped a few times where a particular variable came from because it was neither declared nor a parameter so I guessed that it must be a class member - having a clear visual queue help. However that's a personal style preference so YMMV.
2. Not sure why you have prefixed `filePath` with an `@` when you use it. This is only necessary when you want to name a variable the same name as a C# keyword like `this` (so you could have a local variable called `@this` for example).
3. You shouldn't use `as` like this:

   > ```
   > (backgroundWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressPercentage, fileCount);
   > ```

   Either you're sure it's a `BackgroundWorker` then use a direct cast or you're not sure then use `as` plus a `null` check. The way it stands you might get a `NullReferenceException` which is usually not very helpful (since technically this could be thrown in a lot of different places). With a direct cast you get at least an `InvalidCastException` which tells you a lot more about what may have caused it.
4. `DeAccentTitles` should not have to deal with a collection but should just deal with an individual title - it should not concern itself with the requirement that you want to do this for a whole collection of strings. It can also be condensed with the use of LINQ:

   ```
   private string DeAccentTitle(string title)
   {
       var chars = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
                    .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                    .ToArray()
       return new string(chars).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)
   }
   ```
5. Based on the above point `LoadXML` can be condensed as well. Especially the `null` handling should just disappear:

   ```
   private List<string> LoadXML(string filePath, string descendant, string element)
   {
       return XDocument.Load(filePath)
                       .Root
                       .Descendants(descendant)
                       .Where(c => c.Element("type").Value == "TV")
                       .Select(c.Element(element).Value)
                       .OrderBy(v => v)
                       .Select(DeAccentTitle)
                       .ToList();
   }
   ```
6. Also `RunAnalysis` can be improved. I would also make that the point where the `backgroundWorker` is cast to it's actual type.

   ```
   private void RunAnalysis(object backgroundWorker)
   {
       titles = LoadXML(animeDBPath, "item", "name");

       var allFiles = dirList.SelectMany(d => d.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                             .SelectMany(d => d.EnumerateFiles())
                             .ToList();

       sortedFiles = SortFiles(allFiles, (BackgroundWorker)backgroundWorker);
   }
   ```

---

**Update** for the `SortFiles` method

A few things to improve here:

1. You split strings in the same way three times - I find it cleaner to extract this into a common method to perform that action.
2. I would extract the scoring of a single title against a specific file name into it's own method - this encapsulates the core scoring logic and then lets you deal with the scoring of all file names in a more condensed way.
3. After you've done 1 and 2 you can apply some LINQ magic again to make it more succinct.
4. I don't have the code of the `Category` class but since the `Category.Name` seems to be linked to the title name it seems weird that you'd have to pass this in for every file you add. The code would become a bit cleaner if this is tidied up - I haven't that in the below code yet though.

The refactored code for the `SortFiles` looks like this:

```
private string[] SplitByRemovables(string value)
{
    return value.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

private int ScoreTitle(string title, string[] filenameParts, string[] directoryParts)
{
    var score = filenameParts.Count(p => Regex.IsMatch(title, @"\b" + p + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    if (score > 0)
    {
        score += directoryParts.Count(p => Regex.IsMatch(title, @"\b" + p + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    }

    // if the percentage of word matches and total words in the title is > 80% (arbitrary)
    // To avoid false matches with longer titles boost the score
    int titleWordCount = SplitByRemovables(title).Length;
    if ((100 * score / (2 * titleWordCount)) > 80)
    {
        score += 2;
    }
    return score;
}

private List<Category> SortFiles(List<FileInfo> allFiles, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    int fileCount = 0;

    foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
    {
        fileCount++;

        var filenameParts = SplitByRemovables(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
        var directoryParts = SplitByRemovables(file.Directory.Name);

        var topTitle = titles.Select(t => new { Title = t, Score = ScoreTitle(t, filenameParts, directoryParts) })
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
                             .First();

        var childFile = new Children(file);

        if (topTitle.Score > 0)
        {
            var category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == topTitle.Title);
            if (category == null)
            {
                category = new Category(childFile, topTitle.Title);
                categories.Add(category);
            }
            else
            {
                category.AddChildren(childFile, topTitle.Title);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Files without a score were not matched with any existing category
            notSortedFiles.Add(childFile);
        }

        // Update Progress
        // Send percentComplete to the backgroundWorker and the current file number
        int progressPercentage = 100 * fileCount / allFiles.Count;
        // Only the ReportProgress method can update the UI
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage, fileCount);
    }
    return categories;
}
```

Just saw in the comments to your question that you've identified some speed issues with the regular expressions. One potential change you could make is to replace those by simple string matching. The refactored code in this case would look like this:

```
private string[] SplitByRemovables(string value)
{
    return value.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

private int ScoreTitle(string[] titleParts, string[] filenameParts, string[] directoryParts)
{
    var score = filenameParts.Intersect(titleParts).Count();
    if (score > 0)
    {
        score += directoryParts.Intersect.(titleParts).Count();
    }

    // if the percentage of word matches and total words in the title is > 80% (arbitrary)
    // To avoid false matches with longer titles boost the score
    if ((100 * score / (2 * titleParts.Length)) > 80)
    {
        score += 2;
    }
    return score;
}

private List<Category> SortFiles(List<FileInfo> allFiles, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    int fileCount = 0;
    var splitTitles = titles.Select(t => new { Title = t, Parts = SplitByRemovables(t) }).ToList();

    foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
    {
        fileCount++;

        var filenameParts = SplitByRemovables(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
        var directoryParts = SplitByRemovables(file.Directory.Name);

        var topTitle = splitTitles.Select(t => new { Title = t.Title, Score = ScoreTitle(t.Parts, filenameParts, directoryParts) })
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
                                  .First();

        var childFile = new Children(file);

        if (topTitle.Score > 0)
        {
            var category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == topTitle.Title);
            if (category == null)
            {
                category = new Category(childFile, topTitle.Title);
                categories.Add(category);
            }
            else
            {
                category.AddChildren(childFile, topTitle.Title);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Files without a score were not matched with any existing category
            notSortedFiles.Add(childFile);
        }

        // Update Progress
        // Send percentComplete to the backgroundWorker and the current file number
        int progressPercentage = 100 * fileCount / allFiles.Count;
        // Only the ReportProgress method can update the UI
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage, fileCount);
    }
    return categories;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great advice! I'm still new to LINQ so am not familiar with 'Best Practices'. And I thought the `@` prefix in `filepath` is to avoid accidental C# keyword creations if a filename contained `this` etc. I could be wrong about this assumption though.

Comment: I have added class level variables declarations for more context. Should I paste the whole file instead? It has a few front-end related event handlers (~300 lines).

Comment: @ParasDPain: You could post a follow up question with the complete code incorporating all the suggestions you deem useful from this one.

Comment: @ParasDPain: I've updated my answer with the remaining code reviewed.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I will post a follow-up question after implementing these suggestions. Cheers

Comment: I've posted the follow up question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117304/categorize-episode-file-names-follow-up)